# How to take away on a variable? (batch)

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm making a quick pass protected batch (gonna make it a .exe later) and I would like to make it delete itself when the tries variable reaches 0, but I can't figure out how to make check if tries is 0, or to take away from the variable, quick example:

```
set %tries%=3
set /P c=Please Enter The Password; You Have %tries% Attempts Remaining
if /I "%c%" EQU "Pass" goto :command_hub

(insert a thing that checks if 0 and then takes 1 if not)

goto :delete
:delete
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
```

Comment: type `set /?` and read the output. Take special notice of the `/a` switch.

Comment: In the help file for the `SET` command, it actually talks about the the `/A` usage before the `/P` usage. Not sure how you missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set %tries%=3
set /P c=Please Enter The Password; You Have %tries% Attempts Remaining
if /I "%c%" EQU "Pass" goto :command_hub

(insert a thing that checks if 0 and then takes 1 if not)
```

should be

```
set /a tries=3
:retry
set /P c=Please Enter The Password; You Have %tries% Attempts Remaining
if /I "%c%" EQU "Pass" goto command_hub
set /a tries-=1
if %tries% gtr 0 goto retry
```

Setting `%tries%` sets a variable called *the current content of tries*

set /a performs arithmetic operations. It's optional when assigning a numeric value like `3`.

see `set /?` from the prompt for documentation.

The `goto :label` command is *valid* but the colon is not required **except in the specific case of** `goto :eof` which means 'go to the end of the file' (which terminates a routine) The label `:eof` is understood and should not be programmed.

Comment: `s/leq/geq/` :)

Comment: @rojo s/leq/gtr/ !banana

Comment: Thanks dude! learnt even more than I thought I would today :)